Pydantic: remove discriminated union discriminator value from ValidationError loc field
I am currently using FastAPI for a university project, where it serves as my backend.
One of the flows of my application requires me to send a payload from the front-end to the back-end, where one of the fields has many variants. This payload needs to be validated with pydantic in the back-end. For this, I decided to go with a discriminated union.
Let's assume that the class is structured this way.
class ClassA(pydantic.BaseModel):
    type: Literal["a"]
    field_a: int

class ClassB(pydantic.BaseModel):
    type: Literal["b"]
    ...

ClassUnion = Annotated[Union[ClassA, ClassB], pydantic.Field(discriminator="type")]

class Parent(pydantic.BaseModel):
    child: ClassUnion
    field_parent: str

I have a Parent class, which has a child field which contains a union of ClassA and ClassB, discriminated by type. So if the type field in the JSON payload contains "a", pydantic will resolve it to ClassA. The discriminated union works in the happy path (when there's no errors), however, if I fill child.field_a with an invalid value (say, a string), I expect a ValidationError to be raised so that the back-end can notify the front-end about where the error is located.
To do this, I have a custom error handler which catches any RequestValidationError from FastAPI, transform the various errors from pydantic's ValidationError into a simpler shape. The details of the error handler doesn't matter; what matters is that the error handler depends on the "loc" field on ValidationError.
For example, if an error occurs in "field_parent", then the "loc" field will point to the location of the error; that being ("body", "field_parent"). Note that "body" is just where the error occurred in the FastAPI request. We can assume that the loc is just ("field_parent") for simplicity's sake.
However, if an occurs in "field_a", then I expect that the loc should be: ("child", "field_a"). This way, I can transform the field into a shape that matches the input:
{
    "child": {
        "field_a": "Error message"
    }
}

However, it seems that pydantic includes the discriminated union discriminator into the "loc" field as well. Remember that "field_a" is in a discriminated union (ClassA, to be specific) and is discriminated by "type". If type = "a", then "child" becomes ClassA. This discriminator value ends up being included in the "loc", becoming ("child", "a", "field_a"). This obviously messes with my front-end exception handler, as the fields are no longer matched with the input.
Is there any way to remove the discriminator value from loc field? I did not find any option that can disable this behavior (if it can even be disabled at all) in the FastAPI discriminated union documentation. This is not a problem about how to customize FastAPI request validation errors; but rather a problem with how Pydantic formats the "loc" field
Alternative solutions:

I've considered using WrapValidators to catch the ValidationError and then modify it somehow, but there's few documentation about the internals of ValidationError (Looking at the python code doesn't help either, since it's probably implemented elsewhere).

Manually filtering the discriminated union values seems like a dirty solution, and there's also the risk of a discriminator sharing the same name as a field, so I decided against it as well.

I cannot just customize error validation for a specific route or two since the model will be reused across several routes.


Any suggestions?
